# Div selector with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I have a page where I want to put a selector where the user has different options but he only can select 1 and get the id of that selected part so i can put the id in a link, it has 2 part, i have never used jquery so I'm struggling. Here is how the code of the site looks (it's an example) :

Selector 1

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center su-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center su-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

 <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center su-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Selector 2

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center tu-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center tu-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">

<div id="" class="cuadro center tu-signo">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    <div class="titulo">
<h3 class="red"><small></small></h3>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Jquery so far:

```
<script>
var me = "";
var th = "";
   $(".tu-signo").on('click',function()  {
     me = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).css('-webkit-filter','brightness(50%)');
    });


</script>
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Other than the fact that your divs don't have ids, that code should correctly get an id.

Comment: yes i know that it doesnt have ids its just the example code, my problem is this, when i select the div the div puts the css, but when i select another the past div selected stay with the css

Comment: So your goal is to toggle css?

Comment: How about you [edit] your question to ask precisely what the problem is, and only the code that will reproduce the problem? Right now I have no idea what the difference is between "Selector 1" and "Selector 2", because I'm not going to comb through that much code looking for difs...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Basically this is what I want to do http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/product-chooser-selector

Comment: Your boot snip example is very different than your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue when developing websites. A typical example would be when you want to add an active class to a navigation element or selecting tabs.

What you have to do is loop through all the items that could have the CSS class you're looking for and remove it. Then add the CSS class to the current element.

In my example below you can see that we remove the `.active` class from all the navigation items then add `.active` to the element that was clicked.

```js
$links = $( '.nav a' );

$links.on( 'click', function (e ) {

  $links.removeClass( 'active' );
  $( this ).addClass( 'active' );

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

For your use I would suggest using a CSS class rather than the `.css()` method which will add inline styles to your element. It's much easier to add/remove/toggle a class than a handful of inline styles.

Here is another example that is doing something a little closer to what you want to do.

```js
$links = $( '.nav a' );
$id = $( '.id' );

$links.on( 'click', function (e ) {

  var $this = $( this );

  $links.removeClass( 'active' );      
  $this.addClass( 'active' );
  $id.val( $this.attr( 'id' ) );  

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <a id="home" class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
  <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
</nav>
<input class="id" type="text" name="id">
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` with `removeClass`. All the modification methods in jQuery can be called directly on a collection and will operate on all the elements.

Comment: You are correct, been a little while using some methods. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to bring your other selector back to your original brightness, this should work.

```
<script>
var me = "";
   $(".tu-signo").on('click',function()  {
     me = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".tu-signo").css('-webkit-filter','YOUR ORIGINAL BRIGHTNESS HERE');
        $(this).css('-webkit-filter','brightness(50%)');
    });


</script>
```

This will bring all `.tu-signo` classes back to your original brightness before changing the one you clicked on. And I'm not sure what the `var th;` was for so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery if you want it to hide the existing choice when you change it, you need to add the removal function, its not intuitive to this.

(This is assuming i understand what you're wanting to achieve.

ie.

`var me = "";
     var th = "";
      $(".tu-signo").on('click',function()  {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == "option1") {
               $('#option1').css('-webkit-filter','brightness(50%)');
               $('#option2').hide();
          }
          if ($(this).attr("id") == "option2") {
               $("#option2").css('-webkit-filter','brightness(50%)');
               $("#option1").hide();
           }
      });`